# Value for key xsi:type is missing in the argument data

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.9

I've just moved my M 2.2.9 site from my dev server to my live server & I'm getting the following errors. Needless to say, it's all working fine on the dev server.

I've disabled all extensions without making any progress. Anyone have any clues?

```
{"0":"Value for key \"xsi:type\" is missing in the argument data.","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Block->evaluateArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Reader\/Block.php:169]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Block->scheduleBlock() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Reader\/Block.php:138]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Block->interpret() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/ReaderPool.php:105]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\ReaderPool->interpret() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Reader\/Container.php:89]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Container->interpret() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/ReaderPool.php:105]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\ReaderPool->interpret() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php:325]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:89]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php:129]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Page\/Builder.php:55]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Page\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php:65]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->build() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php:253]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->build() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php:875]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:414]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-cms\/Helper\/Page.php:171]\n#15 Magento\\Cms\\Helper\\Page->prepareResultPage() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-cms\/Controller\/Index\/Index.php:68]\n#16 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index->execute() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Cms\/Controller\/Index\/Index\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#17 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:107]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#19 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#20 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#21 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Cms\/Controller\/Index\/Index\/Interceptor.php:39]\n#22 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:55]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#25 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]\n#26 Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]\n#28 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#30 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#31 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:136]\n#32 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#33 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:257]\n#34 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was due to a corrupted file during the transfer from one server to another. Re-doing the transfer seems to have resolved the issue.